# Parsing Git log numstats into R table

Tags: r, git

I am trying to use R to calculate some statistics on my git repo, and am trying to figure out how to parse the format git --numstats give into an r table, but I am having difficulty parsing the output.  How do I parse the output?

I am using the following git command to pull needed data from the log:

```
git log --pretty=format:"[%H],%an,%ae,%aD,%aI,%x22%s%x22" --numstat  --perl-regexp --no-merges > Commits.txt
```

This creates output similar to this

(Columns: "Hash", "Name", "Email", "Day", "Date", "DateISO8608", "Subject")

```
[b5db76a6403a2354e46fa9bbcc314689adb3a75d],AuthorName1,Author1Email@email.com,Fri, 27 Oct 2017 11:38:31 -0700,2017-10-27T11:38:31-07:00,"Some subject line"
31      1       MergedComponents/SourceFolder/sources.cpp
2       0       MergedComponents/SourceFolder/sources.h

[81da4b2cf2531e7a5e771d0dc8e344dd9ad69843],AuthorName2,Author2Email@email.com,,Fri, 27 Oct 2017 11:08:13 -0700,2017-10-27T11:08:13-07:00,"Another subject line"
24      0       MergedComponents/SourceFolder/sources.cpp
1       2      MergedComponents/SourceFolder/sources.h
```

I am stuck on how to create a table with one row per source file. So that the columns are like this:

Columns ("Hash", "AuthorName", "Email", "Day", "Date", "DateISO8608", "Subject", "*LinesAdded*", "*LinesDeleted*", "SourceFile*")

So far I have the following R code (see below) but I am getting stuck when trying to combine the current source line with the previous metadata line.

```
# data was created via
# git log --pretty=format:"[%H],%an,%ae,%aD,%aI,%x22%s%x22" --numstat  --no-merges > Commits.txt
allData <- readLines("Commits.txt");

head(allData);

# find all lines that start with [
commitEntries = grep("^\\[", allData)

# create table for the commit metadata
commitTable = read.table(text = allData[commitEntries], sep = ",")
colnames(commitTable) <- c("Hash","Name","Email","Day","Date","DateISO8608","Subject")
head(commitTable)    

#create table for each file
numOfLines <- length(allData)
lastHeaderLine <- ""
for (i in 0:numOfLines) {
    if (i %in% commitEntries) {
        lastCommitMetaLine <- allData[i]
        i = i + 1
        while (!(i %in% commitEntries) & i < numOfLines) {
            print(c(lastCommitMetaLine, allData[i]))
            # how to append lastCOmmitMetaLine joined to allData[i] to a table row??
            i=i+1
        }
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 3):

You can try my [gitsum](https://github.com/lorenzwalthert/gitsum) package that was written to parse git repository history. It can parse detailed file-specific information, e.g. you get a table where each changed file in a commit corresponds to one row and you can see how many lines in that file got changed.